# mysql showing null values for group by statements

Tags: sql, mysql, null, group-by

I'm doing:

```
   select sum(clicks), 
          date 
     from stats 
 group by date
```

...however when the sum is null for some date, the whole row is discarded, I want to see: `| null | some_date |`, how to do so?

Comment: It would help to see the full query in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help to see the full query in question. For every date value that exists in `stats`, you should either get NULL for the Sum or an integer value. If you are grouping by [Date] and a given date value does not exist, it obviously will not show up. E.g., consider the following test:

```
Create Table Test ( Clicks int null, [Date] datetime null )
Insert Test(Clicks,[Date]) Values(1,'2010-06-06')
Insert Test(Clicks,[Date]) Values(2,Null)
Insert Test(Clicks,[Date]) Values(3,'2010-06-06')
Insert Test(Clicks,[Date]) Values(4,'2010-06-07')
Insert Test(Clicks,[Date]) Values(4,Null)
Insert Test(Clicks,[Date]) Values(4,'2010-06-07')
Insert Test(Clicks,[Date]) Values(Null,'2010-06-08')

Select T.[Date], Sum(Clicks)
From Test T
Group By T.[Date]
```

The results should look like:

```
NULL                       6
2010-06-06 00:00:00.000 4
2010-06-07 00:00:00.000 8
2010-06-08 00:00:00.000 NULL
```

Note I still get a row even when `Sum(Clicks)` is null. Is it that you are joining this information to something else on the `Sum(Clicks)` calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing a group by date, I assume you have more than one record per date.  I would think you'd have to `ifnull` on the original data, or you will lose some.

For example, if Jun 10th had counts of 10, 20, 30 and null, you'd get null instead of 60.

I think this will prevent that issue:

```
select ifnull(sum(ifnull(clicks,0)), 'null'), date from stats group by date;
```