# Grouping by date, return row even if no records found

Tags: sql, mysql, date, group-by, datetime-generation

I have a query that groups all entries from a table and groups them by the datetime column. This is all working great:

```
SELECT SUM(  `value` ) AS  `sum` , DATE(`datetime`) AS  `dt``
FROM  `entry` 
WHERE entryid = 85
AND DATETIME BETWEEN  '2010-01-01' AND '2010-03-01'
GROUP BY `dt`
ORDER BY `datetime`
```

**The problem is, I need it to return a row even if nothing is found, with the value set to 0.** I assume there's some MYSQL function that'll take care of this but can't seem to find it.

Thanks!

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022640/mysql-showing-null-values-for-group-by-statements and many others.

Comment: Another that is more similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978129/retrieve-missing-dates-from-database-via-mysql

Comment: @Mark Byers: I added the "datetime-generation" tag, to highlight how common the question is...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have recursive functionality, so you're left with using the NUMBERS table trick -

1. Create a table that only holds incrementing numbers - easy to do using an auto_increment:

   ```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`numbers`;
   CREATE TABLE  `example`.`numbers` (
     `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```
2. Populate the table using:

   ```
   INSERT INTO NUMBERS
     (id)
   VALUES
     (NULL)
   ```

   ...for as many values as you need.
3. Use [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) to construct a list of dates, increasing the days based on the NUMBERS.id value.  Replace "2010-01-01" and "2010-03-01" with your respective start and end dates (but use the same format, YYYY-MM-DD) -

   ```
   SELECT x.*
     FROM (SELECT DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL n.id - 1 DAY)
             FROM numbers n
            WHERE DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL n.id -1 DAY) <= '2010-03-01' ) x
   ```
4. LEFT JOIN onto your table of data based on the datetime portion:

   ```
      SELECT DATE(x.dt) AS dt,
             COALESCE(SUM(e.value), 0) AS sum_value
        FROM (SELECT DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL n.id - 1 DAY) AS dt
                FROM numbers n
               WHERE DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL n.id -1 DAY) <= '2010-03-01' ) x
   LEFT JOIN ENTRY e ON DATE(e.datetime) = x.dt
                    AND e.entryid = 85
    GROUP BY DATE(x.dt)
   ```

### Why Numbers, not Dates?

Simple - dates can be generated based on the number, like in the example I provided.  It also means using a single table, vs say one per data type.