# query records from the mysql DB in date range but not of Sundays

Tags: mysql

Hello I want to query a MySQL database in a date range for last 14 days. And not of Sundays.

The table contains a column with 'Date' datatype.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), table.date) <= 14
AND WEEKDAY(table.date) != 6 #6 is sunday
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Cheers mate.
How can I do like if there are no particular records for a particular date return 0 with the date, instead of not returning any data for that day. For example in db, Mon 2, Tues 6, Wed 8, Fri 2, Sat 8. So, in the query i want it to return Thurs 0. Is it possible please?

Comment: That's tricky. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640151/grouping-by-date-return-row-even-if-no-records-found I would probably do that part with server-side scripting like PHP.

Comment: ok thanks a lot though. your previous example worked perfectly. But i need to do some PHPing now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM 
    tableX AS t
WHERE 
    t.dateColumn >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY
  AND 
    WEEKDAY(t.dateColumn) <> 6 ;
```