# How to get sum of amount for between dates and display disappeared date?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

1. Booking

   id     roomId     checkinDate     checkoutDate    customerId
2. Room

   roomId     Price

I'd like to summarize total amount per day but I don't know how to find and display total amount of a gap between checkinDate and checkoutDate (checkinDate and checkoutDate should be the input from user, ex. checkinDate = '2013-04-01', checkoutDate = '2013-07-01'). I try by myself but I could do only from checkinDate. This is what I did:

```
SELECT DATE(checkinDate), SUM(price) 
FROM booking a INNER JOIN room b on a.roomID = b.roomNo 
WHERE MONTH(checkinDate) = @month and YEAR(checkinDate) = @year
GROUP BY MONTH(checkinDate), DATE(checkinDate)
```

So I got the results like this

```
DATE(checkinDate)    SUM(price)
2013-06-01           3570
2013-06-04           650
```

But what I want should be something like

```
DATE(checkinDate)    SUM(price)
2013-06-01           3570
2013-06-02           xxxx
2013-06-03           xxxx
2013-06-04           650
```

Even if somedays doesn't have any income, it should show 0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grouping by date, return row even if no records found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640151/grouping-by-date-return-row-even-if-no-records-found)

Comment: @iKishore If you think it's an an answer, post it. Code in comments is hard to read and understand.

Comment: @iKishore I already tried that but it returns 0 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be for you to create a calendar table with one row for every date you might be interested in, then `LEFT JOIN` to that table to produce your report.  You can define various other columns in that table to assist in your reporting requirements (such as holiday flags and period indicators).

**[Here is one of many](http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables)** web posts with suggestions on creating such a table.  A web search on "mysql calendar tables" will reveal many others.

For example, assuming you had such a calendar table, you could run a query like this:

```
SELECT cal.calendar_date
     , SUM(b.price) 
FROM calendar cal
LEFT OUTER JOIN booking a
on a.DATE(checkinDate) = cal.calendar_date 
LEFT OUTER JOIN room b 
on a.roomID = b.roomNo 
WHERE cal.calendar_month = @month 
  and cal.calendar_year = @year
GROUP BY cal.calendar_date
```

Calendar tables are really very useful.

Answer (score 0):

With data that you have provided, this is working perfectly for me, and I hope the same for you:

```
SELECT a.checkinDate, SUM(b.price) 
FROM booking AS a LEFT JOIN room AS b on a.roomID = b.roomNo 
WHERE a.checkinDate >= '01-04-2012' AND a.checkoutDate <= '01-07-2012'
GROUP BY a.checkinDate;
```

Since you need report for every dates from **booking** table, *left join* is must. 
Take care about date formatting, you should get the results.

P.S.: query from SQLite 3.3.6